# Is there a way to identify whether a value was successfully found or if it was added when using ConcurrentDictionary.GetOrAdd?

Tags: c#, collections, concurrency, concurrentdictionary

I have some code that uses the `GetOrAdd` function from `ConcurrentDictionary` to add values with a unique key to a holder. However, I want to be able to tell if a values key is found (i.e. a `true` returned from `TryGet`) or whether it has to be added.

I haven't been able to find anything online that suggests this is achievable so if anyone has any ideas it would be really helpful.

Comment: You need to run TryGet.  Then when you have old value you can compare with the value returned from GetOrAdd.  GetOrAdd returns following : The value for the key. This will be either the existing value for the key if the key is already in the dictionary, or the new value for the key as returned by valueFactory if the key was not in the dictionary.

Comment: What [`GetOrAdd`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2.getoradd) overload are you using? The one with parameter `value` or the other with parameter `valueFactory`?

Comment: Although it is not required, it might be interesting to include in the question the reason that you need this feature. What difference does it make if the key already existed, or it was just inserted? I can't think of a scenario where this difference matters.

Comment: Doesn't [TryAdd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2.tryadd?view=net-7.0) do what you want already? What's the actual problem and why aren't the current methods enough? Are you looking for a `TryAdd` that generates the value lazily, the way `GetOrAdd(,Func)` does?

Comment: As @PanagiotisKanavos says, there's `TryOrAdd`. If construction is expensive, consider changing your dictionary from being a `ConcurrentDictionary<TKey,TValue>` to being a `ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, Lazy<TValue>>`. `Lazy` doesn't add much overhead if it's already had to produce its value and you can control concurrency in construction better.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever that assumes that lazy generation is indeed a requirement. Perhaps the real question is knowing whether the value is "new"? Why would that matter? Unless someone is trying to filter duplicate messages by ID? The actual value doesn't matter then, and `TryAdd` is enough.

Comment: This is valid question. Of course, knowing if the value is new can matter because this fact can be part of synchronization mechanism. Marking the returned object is not an option because assessment of this mark can be also made concurrently so unreliable. We have to be atomic here. Using flag inside lambda Func looked promising but it's turned out that if the `GetOrAdd`  has already created a new object but another thread was faster, then it just returned new object created in another thread and drop in limbo the object created there, so it's not reliable either. It's very pity to have a lock

Comment: Maybe you were able to find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

This is my lock-free attempt. `GetOrAdd` can invoke a delegate if at the moment of its calling there was no such key but ultimately can drop return if another thread won. The idea is to create a new object inside the lambda and then compare it with what `GetOrAdd` returns, in case if it was started as "Add", to reduce comparison overhead. It is not yet proven to be reliable but for me looks atomic and performant.

I made it as an extension:

```
public static class ConcurrentDictionaryExtensions
{
    public static bool TryGetOrAdd<TKey, TValue>(
        this ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary,
        TKey key,
        out TValue resultingValue,
        TValue existingValue = null) where TValue : class, new()
    {
        bool added = false;
        TValue newValue = null;

        resultingValue = dictionary.GetOrAdd(key, _ => {
            newValue = existingValue is null ? new TValue() : existingValue;
            added = true;
            return newValue;
        });

        return added && ReferenceEquals(resultingValue, newValue);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
bool isNew = myDictionary.TryGetOrAdd(1, out var resultingValue, [existingValue]);
```

UPD: Added optional argument to pass existing object instead of creating new one. Extension seems to be proven to be reliable.

Answer (score -1):

Not consistently, no. If the method returns something other than the value that you provide then you know that the key already existed but if the key exists and has the same value that you provide then there will be no distinction. If you want to know definitively then you will have to test for the key first. It sounds like your best bet is to call `ContainsKey` first and then call `GetOrAdd`. You could wrap that into your own single method so it's easy to reuse and lock the dictionary if you need it to be atomic.

Comment: This makes `ConcurrentDictionary` update a non-atomic operation.

Comment: @orhtej2, I've made an edit that would address that.